# How to handle hierarchical features

Tags: feature-selection, feature-engineering

I am building a ML model, and the dateset contains some hierarchical features, such as a product has primary category, sub category. For example, a product named "moisture1", it has primaryCategory - "Beauty & Personal Care", and subCategory - "skin Care".

I ask since I feel this might be a common problem, hence wondering if there are standard approaches to tackle it.

Here are some my thoughts:

1. Treat them as separate features, do nothing
2. Leave only either primary category or sub category, and delete the
   other
3. Combine them into one feature in some way
4. I heard "feature embedding" often. I know it is a technique used
   often in NLP and deep learning, but I haven't get time to learn how
   it works exactly. Is it used in problem like this?